# How to search email address by DSE solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene, datastax-enterprise

1. I am trying to write a solr query to search the emailid field and TwitterID field.Query is
    SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE solr_query='twitter:karth@*';
   I am getting null value as result.

   Expected results : It should show all the field which is having karth..because table has 5 row with this emailid

   I am using following Schema.

   name

Comment: have you indexed the data in solr? ARe you querying solr or database?

Comment: I did auto  indexing . and I am querying database